# Is spotbugs compatible with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, spotbugs

When running spotbugs on a Kolin project I get errors such as:

> [ERROR] Private method com.example.CSVRecord.component1() is never called [com.example.CSVRecord] In CSVRecord.kt UPM_UNCALLED_PRIVATE_METHOD

on classes such as:

```
data class CSVRecord(private val columns: SortedSet<CSVColumn>) : Iterable<String> {

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<String> {
        return columns.map { it.value }.iterator()
    }
}
```

I'm not really clear where `component1` came from!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Data Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) documentation:

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all
>   properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> - equals()/hashCode() pair;
> - toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)";
> - componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration;
> - copy() function (see below).

This is one the features of data classes. The auto-generated `componentN` functions allow you to use [Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) on this type of classes:

```
data class Result(val result: Int, val status: Status)
fun function(...): Result {
    // computations

    return Result(result, status)
}

// Now, to use this function:
val (result, status) = function(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [merged PR](https://github.com/spotbugs/sonar-findbugs/pull/569) with Kotlin support in SpotBugs mentioned here:
https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/573